# How do I place jAlerts in relation to div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div called input, how do I show the jAlert beside this div?

jAlert: http://www.smooka.com/blog/2009/02/22/jalert-jquery-alert-box-plugin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code sample to manually set the css of jAlert :
1. First you have to get uid that jAlert library uses.
2. Then just set the css of jalert_overlay_ element.

```
 if (uid == undefined)
    {   //generate an unique ID
        var d = new Date();
        var uid = d.getMonth()+""+d.getDate()+""+d.getHours()+""+d.getMinutes()+""+d.getSeconds();

        }

$("#jalert_overlay_"+uid).css({
                                              top: 0, 
                                              left: 0, 
                                              width: overlayWidth, 
                                              height: overLayHeight, 
                                              position: "fixed",
                                              display: "block",
                                              background: "#000",
                                              zIndex: "1000"
                                          })
                $("#jalert_overlay_"+uid).css("opacity", 0.7);
```

Hope this would help you. If you have any further questions, Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

> ```
> var divInput= $("#input").position();
> ```

```
$("#jAlertId").css('position','absolute')    //if position is not absolute already
$("#jAlertId").css('top',divInput.top+2).css('left',divInput.left+2);   //+2 or whatever figure u need
```